# Count number of updates

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have some postgresql tables, and I want to know if there is any possibility to count the number of updated rows?

To be more clear is being able to count the number of updates that may occur on a table.

Comment: The number of updates that _may_ occur? Infinite

Comment: Yes, I want to count the rows which may be affected by updates operations that users will do.

Comment: Well, that number is infinite. Users can do as many update operations as they want

Comment: Yes, that's it. Users can operate as many modifications as they want

Comment: So again the answer is: infinite. You can't predict what they will do.

Comment: Yes the updates are infinite. They can update whatever they want.

Comment: So **what** is your question?

Comment: I want to know if there is a possibility to count the number of rows affected by updates that users may do?

Answer (score 5):

For example by using `RETURNING`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE t(i INT);

INSERT INTO t(i) VALUES (1),(2),(3);

WITH cte AS
(
    UPDATE t
    SET i = i * 10
    WHERE i > 1
    RETURNING *   
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_of_rows_updated
FROM cte;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/DDGCVH44263)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yet what I wanna do is count all the updates that may occur on the table.

Comment: @zakariamouqcit So your description and example is somehow misleading. You should mention in question that you want update counter per table not per statement.

Answer (score 0):

These extension might helpful:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgstatstatements.html
Then a query like:
 select count(*) from pg_stat_statements where query ~* 'update.*your_table';
might provide what you are looking for.