# Counting number of updates

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

Hi Every one I created this trigger function to count number of rows affected by an update .

```
create table smt (
id serial primary key,
    num int
)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_updated()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
    n int;
BEGIN 
    IF(TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN       
        get diagnostics n = row_count;
        insert into smt (num) values (n);
        return null;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$;

CREATE TRIGGER count_updt
AFTER UPDATE  ON test
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE count_updated();
```

what I want to do is store the number of updated rows of `test` in `smt` using  `GET DIAGNOSTICS`, but when I read the content of smt table, the field which is reserved to stock the row_count is 0 even after an update. 
If you have any idea in-light me. 
Cordially.

Comment: Looks so similiar to [Count number of updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019137/count-number-of-updates) before edit.

Comment: why not `select n_tup_upd from pg_stat_all_tables where relname = 'test'`?.. at all why you do it?.. just get diagnostics on update - why over trigger, saving value elsewhere and thes selecting it...

Comment: @Vao Tsun Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to just get amount of updates (and possibly compare before and after some statements, you can just

```
select n_tup_upd from pg_stat_all_tables where relname = 'test'
```

Otherwise you can use `GET DIAGNOSTICS` straight with update (for plpgsql) and `update ... returning` with CTE and `count(1)` for sql. using trigger, saving amount to table and selecting it looks an overhead indeed