# Record old is not assigned yet

Tags: postgresql

I wrote this trigger function to count the number of new inserted rows and store it in a table :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.count_inserted()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$

DECLARE 
n int;
BEGIN 
    n = 0;
    IF(TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN  
        IF (NEW.date = OLD.date) THEN
            update ouf set crt = crt+1 where date = new.date;
            return null;
         ELSE
             insert into ouf (crt,date) values (n+1,now());
             return null;
         END IF;
    END IF;
    return null;
END;

$BODY$;

CREATE TRIGGER count_insrt
    AFTER INSERT
    ON public.test
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.count_inserted();
```

But when I try to insert a new row, I get this error :

> Record old is not assigned yet

If you have any idea about the origin of this error tell me please.

Comment: on insert, there is no OLD version of row - only NEW - you can compare `IF (NEW.date = OLD.date) THEN` if row did not exist before you insert

Answer (score 0):

as I answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47041325/5315974
you should not save such stats with trigger. Just like for updates, you can query `pg_stat` views for inserts:

```
select n_tup_ins from pg_stat_all_tables where relname = 'test';
```

now if you want it aggregated daily (assuming from `OLD.date`) you can just

```
insert into ouf (crt,date) 
select n_tup_ins, now()::date from pg_stat_all_tables where relname = 'test';
```

once a day - not on every insert